# Is there a export to server option available for versions after 2.79?

Tags: rendering

Blender 2.79 had a export to server option.

Why was this removed and is a add on available for subsequent versions?

I have searched and haven't found anything specifically for Blender on Linux.

Comment: What is export to server and what did it do? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: sir ty for your prompt reply.  in blender 2.79 there is an option in properties called output. if you click on it you can choose the output format. one of those options is frame server. why is this option not available in  2.83?

Comment: So I guess you talk about the [Frame Server Output "format"](https://i.imgur.com/5Ky7Uet.png). Which AFAIK was quite clunky, [undocumented](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/search.html?q=frame+server&check_keywords=yes&area=default) (I remember spending hours trying to find a tutorial about it back in v2.6x I think), and seem to have been removed five years ago during the v2.8 Code Quest: [#54387 - 2.8: Code-Quest (Topics we plan to cover) - blender - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/54387#user-content-remove-features)

Comment: Again, afaik: this feature was never fully fledged, and to my knowledge unnecessary for server rendering. So, no you don't have this output available anymore since 5 years ago, but whatever you tried to do with it is very probably possible to do with a different method. So I propose you do post a new thread explaining what you want to achiever and we will have the pleasure to try and find a way to do it with you.

Comment: https://flamenco.blender.org/